# What is the proper way to save and/or autosave a vim session?

Tags: vim

You can create a session with

```
:mksession [sessionName.vim]
```

But if you later modify that session (ie. add/remove buffers) you have to manually save the session again, but doing so will generate the following error

```
E189: "Session.vim" exists (add ! to override)
```

which is an error you generally get with `Save As` not `Save`. So I have two questions:

1. Is there no `Save` functionality here?
2. Is there a way to `autosave` all changes to the session file?

Note: I am aware that I can issue `mksession! sessionName.vim` to overwrite an existing session file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. AFAIK `mksession!` is really the only way to go.
2. You can do it very easily, with just one line in your `vimrc`:
   `au VimLeavePre * if v:this_session != '' | exec "mks! " . v:this_session | endif`

Of course there are plugins that help you save/load and automate saving sessions. Try searching http://vim.org for session.

Comment: If my PhD in vim is still up to date, I am assuming that line states that if the current session is not empty (a session exists), overwrite the current session

Comment: Yes. And it executes right before vim quit, so your session is *updated* to the latest state. That's the behavior you want, right?

Comment: I just removed this from my .vimrc file. If for whatever reason vim fails to load the buffers, when you exit it will save the changes to your Session (which is obviously something you don't want)